# How to use JavaScript in Highcharter?

Tags: javascript, r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to reproduce the following Highcharts graph in `R`, using `highcharter`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/abx6vy9g/

Most of it is just changing the syntax to the R highcharter syntax (using `hchart()` and `hc_plotOptions()` etc.). However, I'm not sure how to reproduce the JavaScript part. I guess it might go within `hchart()`? Unfortunately I seem unable to find any documentation on how exactly to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: here is an example that incorporates javascript into `hc_chart()` and `events` as in your `jsfiddle`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439506/3460670

Comment: Amazing, simple as that apparently! Thanks Ben. If you want you can write this as an Answer and I can accept it (for prosperity)?